# Select all the boxes withing a provided shape (magic wand tool)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I'm trying to recreate the magic wand tool, that selects everything within a shape. The red boxes define the shape and the blue is where the user clicks as demonstrated in fig 1: I have the code for where the user click as `x, y` and asuming they are pixel data.

[image]

Fig 1.

I have a 2-dimensional array e.g, a example circle:

```
var boxes = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
]
```

---

```
$("main").on("mousedown", function(e) 
{
    var offset = $(this).offset();

    var x = e.pageX-offset.left;
    var y = e.pageY-offset.top;

    // ...
});
```

---

What is the best algorithm I can use to turn all the `0` in circle shape to `2` ? Is there any sample code I could use for Javascript ?

Comment: Google "Flood Fill Algorithm" which is usally implemented using recursion.  http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/ZLw9m/

Answer (score 1):

```
function floodFill(boxes, x_click, y_click) {

    var cells = [], x=x_click, y = y_click, arr=boxes.slice(0), hei=arr.length, wid=arr[0].length;
    function check(y,x){
        if(arr[y][x]==0){arr[y][x]=2;cells.push({x:x,y:y})}
    }
    if (arr[y][x]==1){return arr;}
    cells.push({x:x,y:y});
    arr[y][x]==2;
    while(cells.length!=0){
        var cell=cells.slice()[0];
        cells.shift();
        if(cell.y>0){
            check(cell.y-1,cell.x);
        }
        if(cell.y+1<hei){
            check(cell.y+1,cell.x)
        }
        if(cell.x>0){
            check(cell.y,cell.x-1);
        }
        if(cell.x+1<wid){
            check(cell.y,cell.x+1)
        }        
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Full fiddle with your example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dz9nY/1/